# draw line pass a point while minimizing distance with others

Tags: geometry, numerical-linear-algebra, matlab, regression, interpolation

I have a set of points (X0,Y0), (X1,Y1)(Xn,Yn). How can I draw a line that pass through (X0,Y0) and have minimum distance with other points (X1,Y1)(Xn,Yn) e,g by matlab, C, fortran etc?
Thanks

Comment: You need to define what is minimum distance with $n$ points, is it minimum of minimum distance, minimum of maximum distance or minimum sum of distances. For example, consider two cases with $n=2$. Let for first line one distance is 1 and other is 3, and for second line one distance is 1.5 and other is 2.5, and for third line one distance is 1.9 and second is 2.0. What line is preferrable?

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. I mean how can I draw this line so that pass (X0,Y0) and minimize sum of distances with (X1,Y1)....(Xn,Yn).

Answer (score 0):

General equation of line passing through $(x_0,y_0)$ is $y=y_0+k(x-x_0)$, so there is only affecting parameter $k$. We can rewrite this equation like $kx-y+y_0-kx_0=0$. Then distance from point $(x_i,y_i)$ to this line is equal $d_i=\frac{|kx_i-y_i+y_0-kx_0|}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$. Then sum of distances is equal $D(k)=\frac{\sum_i{|kx_i-y_i+y_0-kx_0|}}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$. Then the problem transforms to problem of minimization of function of one variable.

If there is no $x_i$ which is equal to $x_0$, then we can limit search of $k$ with interval $k\in [\min \frac{y_i-y_0}{x_i-x_0};\max \frac{y_i-y_0}{x_i-x_0}]$. We can make plot of $D(k)$ with necessary accuracy to find the minimum.

The analytical method of solution is to divide possible $k$ values on regions where $|kx_i-y_i+y_0-kx_0|$ have constant signs. The simplest way to do it is calculation of $k_i=\frac{y_i-y_0}{x_i-x_0}$ and sorting set of $k_i$. Then in any interval $k\in(k_i;k_{i+1})$ between neighboring values of $k_i$ we can expand all $|kx_i-y_i+y_0-kx_0|$ and get linear expression, then in this interval $D(k)=\frac{a_ik+b_i}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$. Then we can find minimum value  $D_i$ of this function in this interval. After calculation of all $D_i$ we can choose minimal $D_i$, corresponding $k$ value is the slope of a sought line.

Comment: I have employed your suggestion that works. Thank you so much